# Use Variables during deployment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant

I do have some configuration files. Currently these files are completely written manually. But some parts do change from time to time, like version number or current year.
In my ant scripts I could define some variables within the config files and replace these variables during my deployment with the current values. But I do use ant for the full automated nightly build. For normal and interactive work with the software, I do use Eclipse directly without any ant target.

Does anyone know any way how to replace such variables also within Eclipse deployment?

Of course, I could keep my source-config file with variables and use ant to create the final config file also in the source folder which is deployed and used, so both are checked in. But this is also redundant information and looky like a hack to me!

Because of so many misunderstandings:

I would like to have a source-config file with e. g. @MY-VAR@ within the text. During deployment, this placeholder is replaced by a variable value known at compile time. This is possible with ant. Can I do something similar with Eclipse?

Comment: Do you look at System Properties ?

Comment: No, no system properites. I added the last two sections to the question, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How do you read the variables? I would go for system wide properties, this will also work on Linux and Windows platforms and can be changed from computer to computer.

Comment: In ant I just can define e. g. @MY-VAR@ within a text file and can replace this variable name with any variable known by ant script during copying it from source to delopyment folder. The result file is XML but that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing in Java ?

Would this be helpful ?
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm

Comment: Yes, I do develop in Java. But no, I don't need to set environment variables (I know about this options) but would like to do the same as I do with my ant scripts: Adapt my settings and configuration files to some details, known at compile time but not to be modified by customer too easily.